# How to call a function in an if-else statement?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

Trying to call the pushChar function inside an if-else at the bottom, the alert will run but not the function. What am I doing wrong?

I have a feeling it's something to do with the scope but I'm very new to this so possible it's not.

It's a password generator that pulls from an array created by options chosen by the user. I want to unsure that all of the requirements are in the final password and if not, then re-run the function that creates the password.

```
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
    var password = generatePassword();
    var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

    passwordText.value = password;

}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);

//Generate password
function generatePassword() {

//finding out how many characters the user wants in the password with a set range of 8-128
var pwLength = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number between 8-128"));
  while (pwLength < 7 || pwLength > 129 || isNaN(pwLength) || pwLength === null) {
      alert("That's not a valid number. Please enter a number from 8-128.");
      pwLength = prompt("Enter a number between 8-128");
}

//Defining variables
var confirmLower = confirm("Do you want to include lower case characters?");
var confirmUpper = confirm("Do you want to include upper case characters?");
var confirmNumber = confirm("Do you want to include number characters?");
var confirmSpecial = confirm("Do you want to include special characters?");

//If all answers are false, looping back through to get atleast one true response.
while (confirmLower === false && confirmUpper === false && confirmNumber === false && confirmSpecial === false) {
    alert("You need to select one type of character");
    var confirmLower = confirm("Do you want to include lower case characters?");
    var confirmUpper = confirm("Do you want to include upper case characters?");
    var confirmNumber = confirm("Do you want to include number characters?");
    var confirmSpecial = confirm("Do you want to include special characters?");
}

// Various Character Arrays
var lowerCaseChar = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
var upperCaseChar = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
var numericChar = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];
var specialChar = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "{", "}", "|", "[", "]", ";", "'", ":", "<", ">", "?", "/"];

//Array created based on the answers to prompts by the user
var passwordPool = [];

//Creating new array containing the options(arrays) the user chose to include in the password
function generateChar() {
    if (confirmLower) {
        passwordPool.push(...lowerCaseChar);
    }
    if (confirmUpper) {
        passwordPool.push(...upperCaseChar);
    }
    if (confirmNumber) {
        passwordPool.push(...numericChar);
    }
    if (confirmSpecial) {
        passwordPool.push(...specialChar);
    }
}
    generateChar();
    console.log(passwordPool);

   //Creates final array out of random characters from the pool that was created by the users option inputs.
    function pushChar() {
        var randomPassword = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < pwLength; i++) {
            var item = passwordPool[Math.floor(Math.random() * passwordPool.length)];
            randomPassword.push(item);
    }
    return randomPassword;
}
var password = pushChar();


//validate that all of the conditions were met.

var checkUpper = (upperCaseChar.some(ele => password.includes(ele)))
var checkLower = (lowerCaseChar.some(ele => password.includes(ele)))
var checkNumeric = (numericChar.some(ele => password.includes(ele)))
var checkSpecial = (specialChar.some(ele => password.includes(ele)))

console.log(checkUpper);
console.log(checkLower);
console.log(checkNumeric);
console.log(checkSpecial);


if (checkUpper === confirmUpper &&
    checkLower === confirmLower &&
    checkNumeric === confirmSpecial &&
    checkSpecial === confirmNumber) {
    console.log(password);
} else {
        alert("somethings missing");
        console.log(pushChar()); //why won't this run??
}



//Presents randomly generated password to the user as a string. 
  return password.join("");
}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Preferable a stackoverflow code snippet

Comment: If "somethings missing" prints out, that function definitely is running. Along with a [mcve], please describe the behavior you're after, along with what's actually happening.

Comment: Apart from that I am 99.9% sure that if the `alert` runs, then the `console.log` after it is also executed. What I'm not sure is, if the function is declared in the same scope and if you can call it outside of this scope. How do you know that this function is not called?

Comment: @A_A I'm concluding that the function doesn't run because if it did, it would regenerate the password until it met all of the criteria, at the moment that's not happening. It won't even console log a new password - that's why I'm thinking that it's not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems to work for me, only issue my code editor gives is that you never defined generateBtn. Only thing I changed was the vars to lets and consts because my editor was complaining about them.

One issue is that you are redefining checkUpper etc. but that isn't causing your issues. When I run your code (with the vars replaced with lets and consts, I have no idea if that makes a difference), when I get "somethings missing" pushChar does run, but you don't change password and you aren't re-running your checks. I would suggest doing a similar loop you are doing with confirmLower etc. Like so:

```js
const generateBtn = document.querySelector('#generate');

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  const password = generatePassword();
  const passwordText = document.querySelector('#password');

  passwordText.value = password;
}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener('click', writePassword);

// Generate password
function generatePassword() {
  // finding out how many characters the user wants in the password with a set range of 8-128
  let pwLength = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number between 8-128'), 10);
  while (pwLength < 7 || pwLength > 129 || Number.isNaN(pwLength) || pwLength === null) {
    alert("That's not a valid number. Please enter a number from 8-128.");
    pwLength = prompt('Enter a number between 8-128');
  }

  // Defining variables
  let confirmLower = false;
  let confirmUpper = false;
  let confirmNumber = false;
  let confirmSpecial = false;

  // If all answers are false, looping back through to get atleast one true response.
  while (confirmLower === false && confirmUpper === false
    && confirmNumber === false && confirmSpecial === false) {
    alert('You need to select one type of character');
    confirmLower = confirm('Do you want to include lower case characters?');
    confirmUpper = confirm('Do you want to include upper case characters?');
    confirmNumber = confirm('Do you want to include number characters?');
    confirmSpecial = confirm('Do you want to include special characters?');
  }

  // Various Character Arrays
  const lowerCaseChar = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
  const upperCaseChar = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
  const numericChar = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'];
  const specialChar = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '{', '}', '|', '[', ']', ';', "'", ':', '<', '>', '?', '/'];

  // Array created based on the answers to prompts by the user
  const passwordPool = [];

  // Creating new array containing the options(arrays) the user chose to include in the password
  function generateChar() {
    if (confirmLower) {
      passwordPool.push(...lowerCaseChar);
    }
    if (confirmUpper) {
      passwordPool.push(...upperCaseChar);
    }
    if (confirmNumber) {
      passwordPool.push(...numericChar);
    }
    if (confirmSpecial) {
      passwordPool.push(...specialChar);
    }
  }
  generateChar();
  console.log(passwordPool);

  // Creates final array out of random characters from
  // the pool that was created by the users option inputs.
  function pushChar() {
    const randomPassword = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < pwLength; i += 1) {
      const item = passwordPool[Math.floor(Math.random() * passwordPool.length)];
      randomPassword.push(item);
    }
    return randomPassword;
  }

  // validate that all of the conditions were met.
  function checkPassword(password) {
    const checkUpper = (upperCaseChar.some((ele) => password.includes(ele)));
    const checkLower = (lowerCaseChar.some((ele) => password.includes(ele)));
    const checkNumeric = (numericChar.some((ele) => password.includes(ele)));
    const checkSpecial = (specialChar.some((ele) => password.includes(ele)));

    console.log(checkUpper);
    console.log(checkLower);
    console.log(checkNumeric);
    console.log(checkSpecial);

    return checkUpper === confirmUpper
      && checkLower === confirmLower
      && checkNumeric === confirmSpecial
      && checkSpecial === confirmNumber;
  }

  let password = [];
  while (!checkPassword(password)) {
    password = pushChar();
  }

  // Presents randomly generated password to the user as a string.
  return password.join('');
}
```

Comment: Looks like I missed that out from the top, it is defined in there - fixed it up top too.  For the if  statement that is comparing the check and upper, it will do the check, then console log true or false, and if one is false then the alert goes off that something is missing but I would also like it to run the pushChar function to create another password that doesn't return false.

Comment: I am very new too!! Thank you for revisiting this, I'll try out your solution and see if it works @BeFoRe

Comment: This was exactly what I needed!!Thank you

Comment: @mcilhaggis Then please mark it as the accepted answer. (And in the future, please try to make the minimal reproducible example, as described in the links. It helps you to narrow down the problem, and us to quickly understand and reproduce it)